# How to Implement autocorrelation function

Tags: python, machine-learning, hierarchical-clustering, autocorrelation

I am currently working on this assignment problem to Implement the formula for the autocorrelation matrix

=1||∑→∈((→−→)→)(→−→)→

The matrix of standard deviations for two dimensions looks like this:

S   x   y
x               
y

The code obviously is not working, could someone help me where I am getting wrong.Input is an array of the form number_data * dimensions

```
example: example_x = [2,2,2]
example_y = [1,2,3]
example_data = np.stack([[1,2,3], [2,2,2]], axis=1)
```

```
def autocorrelation(data):
    #data is ndimensional array
    #u is the mean
    #s is sd
    x = np.zeros(shape=(data.shape))
    norm=np.linalg.norm(data)
    automatrix=[]
    for row in x:
        centered_data = row - row.mean(axis=0)
        sd=np.std(data)
        c_t=np.transpose(row - row.mean(axis=0))
        a= np.dot([c_t/sd],[centered_data/sd])
        automatrix.append(a)
    return (automatrix/norm)
```

Comment: please give us sample data. thanks.

Comment: Input is an array of the form number_data * dimensions
example: example_x = [2,2,2]
example_y = [1,2,3]
example_data = np.stack([[1,2,3], [2,2,2]], axis=1)